# Undefined offset: 0 in php array

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
if ( count( $entry_array>0 ) )  
{
    $GLOBALS[ 'year' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 5, 2);     //line 22 
    $GLOBALS[ 'month' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 7, 2);    //line 23     
    $GLOBALS[ 'day' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 9, 2);      //line 24     
}
```

> error at line 22, 23, 24 saying Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Any idea to solve this issue..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the content of $entry_array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `if` should read

```
if (count($entry_array) > 0)
```

In your code, you are evaluating `$entry_array > 0`, which would return a boolean. Then you are getting the `count` of that value, which [always usually results in `1` if the argument is not an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

When evaluating `1` as bool (for the if), it evaluates to true, so eventually you execute the body of the `if` even if the array is empty.

So then it is not guaranteed to work, since maybe your array doesn't have index `0`, but likely this was the cause, so I'd try this first.

Comment: plus1: i was writing the same :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count( $entry_array) > 0)   {

//line 22     $GLOBALS[ 'year' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 5, 2);

//line 23     $GLOBALS[ 'month' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 7, 2);

//line 24     $GLOBALS[ 'day' ] = substr($entry_array[0], 9, 2);    }
```

No proper indentation for the if block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($entry_array)>0 && isset($entry_array[0]))
{
  //your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like this,

```
if (count($entry_array)>0)  {
     ....
    }
```

or

```
 if (is_array($entry_array)&&count($entry_array)>0&&isset($entry_array[0]))  {
      ...
     }
```